# firebase function : update document with synchronous rest call

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this scheduled function  that :

1. read 1 document from collection

   ```
   data: [ 
    {
     'field1' : 123,
     'field2' : 456
    },
    {
     'field1' : 123,
     'field2' : 456
    }
    ...
   ]
   ```
2. loop on all data array
3. read new value from rest api call
4. update the value of data array in firestore

**NOTE** from firebase function console log I have the log '**field updated ...**' after the log '**firebase document updated ...**', I think because the request is not sync

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const db = admin.firestore();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
var request = require("request");
const { Headers } = fetch;
exports.onStatisticUpdated = functions.region('europe-west1')
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 300,
  })
  .pubsub.schedule('every 60 minutes')
  .onRun(async context => {
    const doc = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('collection')
      .doc('1234')
      .get();
    if (doc.exists) {
      for (let i = 0; i < doc.data().data.length; i++) {
        let myFirebaseData = doc.data().data[i];
        var options = {
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://xyz....',
          qs: { abcd: 'value' },
          headers: {
            'x-xxxx-host': 'v1....',
            'x-xxxx-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
          }
        }
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
          if (error) throw new Error(error);
          var json = JSON.parse(body);
          if (json['response'].length > 0) {
            console.log('field updated ...');
            myFirebaseData.field1 = json['response'][0].value1
            myFirebaseData.field2 = json['response'][0].value2
          };
        });
      }
      // myFirebaseData is not updated at this time with new value filled by rest api !!!
     console.log(' firebase document updated ...');
      await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('collection')
        .doc('1234')
        .update({
          data: doc.data(),
        });
    }
  });
```

question : how i can store the final document with new values filled by the rest api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloud Functions you need to manage asynchronous method calls via Promises (more details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) in the doc). `request` supports callback interfaces natively **but does not return a Promise**.

You should use another library, like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). In addition, since you want to execute a variable number of asynchronous Rest API calls in parallel, you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Now, what is not clear to me in your code is how do you build the object used to update the `1234` document. I  your current code, in the `for (let i = 0; i < doc.data().data.length; i++) {})` loop you are actually overwriting the `field1` and `field2` properties of the `myFirebaseData` again and again...

Therefore you will find below the code structure/pattern that I think is correct and if it is not the case, just add a comment to this answer and we can fine tune the answer according to the extra details you will share.

```
exports.onStatisticUpdated = functions.region('europe-west1')
    .runWith({
        timeoutSeconds: 300,
    })
    .pubsub.schedule('every 60 minutes')
    .onRun(async context => {
        const doc = await admin
            .firestore()
            .collection('collection')
            .doc('1234')
            .get();

        if (doc.exists) {
            const promises = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < doc.data().data.length; i++) {
                let myFirebaseData = doc.data().data[i];
                var options = {
                    method: 'get',
                    url: 'https://xyz....',
                    params: { abcd: 'value' },
                    headers: {
                        'x-xxxx-host': 'v1....',
                        'x-xxxx-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
                    }
                }
                promises.push(axios(options))
            }
            apiResponsesArray = await Promise.all(promises);

            const updateObject = {};
            apiResponsesArray.forEach((resp, index) => {
                // THIS ENTIRE BLOCK NEEDS TO BE ADAPTED!!
                // I'M JUST MAKING ASSUMPTIONS...
                const responseData = resp.data;
                updateObject["field1" + index] = responseData.value1;
                updateObject["field2" + index] = responseData.value2;

            })

            console.log(updateObject)

            console.log(' firebase document updated ...');
            await admin
                .firestore()
                .collection('collection')
                .doc('1234')
                .update({
                    data: updateObject
                });
                
            return null;  // IMPORTANT!!! see the link to the doc above
        }
    });
```